# Odoo 10 KeyError when installing module

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am working on Odoo 10 since a few months, I made a custom module which depends on some Odoo's modules. 
Today I wanted to create a user manual because my work is almost finished, so I decided to create a new data base to start from zero and be able to explain step by step how to install modules and how it works... 
The problem is, I get this error :

```py
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 882, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 870, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 410, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 339, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 135, in load_module_graph
    registry.setup_models(cr, partial=True)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 293, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields(partial)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/models.py", line 2836, in _setup_fields
    field.setup_full(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/fields.py", line 491, in setup_full
    self._setup_related_full(model)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/fields.py", line 528, in _setup_related_full
    field = target._fields[name]
KeyError: 'workorder_id'
```

Now I am not sure but there seem to be a problem when Odoo should be importing my files because in the database my tables aren't created at all, so I don't know if they aren't created because of this error or if this error is because my tables aren't in the database. 
Anyway, I tried to comment where this workorder_id appears but it didn't change anything, the error is still there, I tried commenting one by one trying to restart the server and all but nothing changes.
I have seen a lot of topics where they talk about inheritance but I don't think that is the case, workorder_id is my own field and it's used in my own models.

Here are the models where this field is used :

```py
class ControlPart(models.Model):
    """
        Modèle pour la vue de la pièce contrôlée.
    """
    _name = 'spc.control.part'

    name                            = fields.Char(string='Piece name')
    starting_date                   = fields.Date(string='Starting date')
    ending_date                     = fields.Date(string='Ending date')
    basket_position                 = fields.Char(string='Basket position')
    piece_number                    = fields.Integer(string='Piece number')
    note                            = fields.Text(string='Notes')
#     operation_workorder_id          = fields.Many2one('spc.fabrication.order', string='Fabrication order', 
#                                                       related='operation_id.workorder_id')
#     operation_workorder_id_product_id  = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product code', 
#                                                      related='operation_id.workorder_id.product_id')

    operation_id        = fields.Many2one('spc.operation', ondelete='restrict', string='Operation') 
    person_id           = fields.Many2one('spc.person', ondelete='restrict', string='Operator')
    workcenter_id       = fields.Many2one('mrp.workcenter', ondelete='restrict', string='Workcenter code')
    control_measure_ids = fields.One2many('spc.control.measure', 'control_part_id', ondelete='restrict', string='Measures')

class Operation (models.Model):
    """
        Modèle pour la vue des opérations.
    """
    _name = 'spc.operation'

    name            = fields.Char(string='Operation name')
    number          = fields.Integer(string='Number')
    pcerp_number    = fields.Char(string='Pro Concept number')

    #workorder_id    = fields.Many2one('spc.fabrication.order', ondelete='restrict', string='Fabrication Order')
```

Thanks for your time !

EDIT : 
So after some time searching for the problem, with my colleague we didn't really find what was wrong. We suppose that Odoo didn't reload files when the service was restarted because we tried to put some wrong code in the files and Odoo simply ignored it.
Maybe something was still in the memory and it kept using the same files, so we managed to resolve the problem finally by killing all the process.
I hope this can still help.

Comment: did you use it in o2m field ?

Comment: Nope, I only use it in Many2one fields

Comment: just creating this field will not cause this error where did you use it.

Comment: I used it in these models I put in the original post and in the view, I also commented it in the view but nothing changed. That's what I don't understand, I didn't use it elsewhere, I read all my models again to try to find it but it's only there in those 2 models and in my views

Comment: did you comment all it's usage? and still get this error this means that you are using it may be in a model that is intalled before the installation of this model

Comment: I commented the whole field, not the whole view if it's what you mean, so the field is disabled and shouldn't be seen as error, I'm sure you're right but I can't find it anywhere. I checked all my files, all my models and views and I don't find it anywhere. 
I will check once more after a break, I'll come back to tell you if I find it somewhere or not... That's a really annoying error

Comment: use you IDE search features to look for usage of the word

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did but it doesn't work properly

Comment: to make sure you are using it right search for something that you used any text you are sure it's exists when you get the result then check for the field name usage most likely is one2many field with inverse_name you didn't create any o2m field at all i had this error before

Comment: I already tested with something else and that's why I said it doesn't work properly, anyway, I'm not able to find where is the error, I'll check again later, maybe I'm too much into the code to see the problem.
Tomorrow I'll check with my colleague, maybe he'll find it.
I will keep you updated.

Comment: and check the name of the database that cause the problem too. may be you should logout from odoo first

Comment: Ok, so we managed to resolve the problem, I'll edit my post with the solution even if it's not that good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the problem, it's not a great solution but it's the only way we found :

> So after some time searching for the problem, with my colleague we
>   didn't really find what was wrong. We suppose that Odoo didn't reload
>   files when the service was restarted because we tried to put some
>   wrong code in the files and Odoo simply ignored it. Maybe something
>   was still in the memory and it kept using the same files, so we
>   managed to resolve the problem finally by killing all the process. I
>   hope this can still help.

Comment: I think you where running two instance of odoo in the same time.

Comment: service odoo force-reload